# I am getting below error when start apache tomcat with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

when I started apache tomcat with spring boot I am getting below exception my component scan and some other annotation :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages =     
{"com.ce.resources","com.ce.services","com.ce.repository"}) 
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ce.repository")
@EntityScan("healthchecker")
@SpringBootApplication
```

2018-10-01 14:22:21.000  WARN 14044 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userprofileResource' defined in file [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\ng-ols-platformservice\WEB-INF\classes\com\ce\resources\UserprofileResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService' defined in file [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\ng-ols-platformservice\WEB-INF\classes\com\ce\services\UserProfileService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileRespository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.ce.entity.UserProfile
2018-10-01 14:22:21.000  INFO 14044 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-10-01 14:22:21.010  INFO 14044 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-10-01 14:22:21.029  INFO 14044 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-10-01 14:22:21.051  INFO 14044 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-01 14:22:21.080 ERROR 14044 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userprofileResource' defined in file [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\ng-ols-platformservice\WEB-INF\classes\com\ce\resources\UserprofileResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService' defined in file [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\ng-ols-platformservice\WEB-INF\classes\com\ce\services\UserProfileService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileRespository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.ce.entity.UserProfile
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245) [catalina.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754) [catalina.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730) [catalina.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985) [catalina.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857) [catalina.jar:8.5.34]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]

Answer (score 0):

Enable jpa repositories to make spring-boot aware that where to find repositories.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ce.repository")
```

Refer this for more info : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html

Comment: thank you..resolved that error.i am getting some other exception can post above please check

Comment: accept the answer if it helped you..and pls create a new question for other exception...thanks